# Save a specific timer tick

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am creating a game in Winforms (c#) and i have made a Timer to have track of the ongoing time and the timer stops when the game stops. But i havent succeded to save the time the timers shows when the game stops and post it.

This is how i have build up the Timer-function.

```
private Timer timers;
public event EventHandler Tick;

StartGame()
{
  ...
  timers = new Timer();
  timers.Interval = 1000;
  timers.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
  timers.Enabled = true;
}

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Time++;
  OnTick();
}

protected void OnTick() 
{
   if (Tick != null) 
   {
      Tick(this, new EventArgs());
   }     
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Time` property?

Comment: For example if i use another winform to save a highscore i want the time to show here.

Comment: I think I see what you want.  You probably want to create your own TickEventArgs class where you inherit from EventArgs and add your Time property to that, so you can pass that information through the event.

Comment: hmm ok, im new to programming and still learning but i think i know how you mean. But i still dont get how i can save the time from there. Do you mind to show a code-example of it?

Comment: Include the value in the constructor `Tick(this, new TickEventArgs(Time));`.  It isn't required.  You can also just cast the `sender` object on the receiving end and get the `Time` property directly.  Probably better to use a StopWatch than an Integer though.  See the posted answer regarding that.

Comment: yeah, the StopWatch feels much better. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Have you considered using MonoGame (open source port of XNA)? It's designed for making games, unlike WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a Timer to measure time - Timers are never accurate, they should be used to trigger events, nothing more. Especially not the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which runs in the GUI thread and can be blocked by other messages.

According to your question you want track game time. Here is how I would do it:

```
private Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();

public void StartOrResumeGame() {
    _sw.Start();
}
public void StopOrPauseGame() {
    _sw.Stop();
    _gameTimeMessage = String.Format("You have been playing for {0} seconds.", _sw.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Stopwatch actually feels better then the timer. But what is the _gameTImeMessage?

Comment: I assumed you were logging game play time to show to the user at the end of the game. Pretend that `_gameTimeMessage` is a message on-screen or something.

Comment: Ok, i think i have made it work now. But im having some trouble with the format. The ".TotalSeconds" does not work and the others i have tried i think shows in milliseconds. Do you have any tips how i can write it out in only seconds? When i use the ".TotalSeconds" i get this error message "'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch' does not contain a definition for 'TotalSeconds' and no extension method 'TotalSeconds' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Sorry, that should be `_sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`. Though the error message is self-explanatory. Did you try to understand what it means and solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Thanks now i get it! Im new to programming and havent learned to understand all of the error-messages yet.

Comment: How can I get this time will automatically be displayed in a database through a label or in a gridview in another form? The way of thinking that it should be like a highscore list.

Comment: That's another question :)

Comment: Do you have any idea? or should i create a new question? :)